# Does we need to sign the tls certs again by peer server?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, tls1.2

I have created Hyperledger fabric setup in one cloud and generated certs with fabric ca. Now I want to use the same cert in another cloud and setup the network again. Does new peer server require to sign the TLS certificates again?

Because when I try to join peer to the channel, I'm facing TLS bad certificate error, I have checked all the configurations and env variables for certs which are set perfectly.

As per the official document we get this error when the peer server not signed the certificate.

Also when i see the tls certificate file name, it has taken private ip. Does this effect anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Did you start Fabric CA `fabric-ca-server start` without init FabricCA `fabric-ca-server init`. Don't init CA because it will generate another private key and public key. If you sure you use all same certificate to start all Fabric component, you will not receive any error about certificate.